# Vuex getters + dev tools

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I started working on a large project that uses extensive number of vuex getters. The problem is, that large amount of them rely to be called in specific order or at specific time to have correct data from other getters. Looks like vue dev tools is trying to access those values, calling the getters not in expected order so some values are not correct and the app is throwing errors. Because of this I cannot use the dev tools and cannot find a simple way around it.
Here is simple snippet reproducing the issue.

This code will run just fine, but once you open dev tools, it tries to access the getter selselectedPrice which returns error until we have some data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in goodThings" :key="item.title">{{ item.title }}</li>
        </ul>
        {{totalPrice}}
    </div>
    <script>

        const getSomeRandomData = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve([
                        {
                            title: 'fasfasf',
                            price: 20
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'asgfasgasg',
                            price: 30
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'asgasgasg',
                            price: 40
                        }
                    ])
                }, 1000)
            })
        }

        const store = new Vuex.Store({
            state: {
                selectedItem: undefined,
                warehouse: []
            },
            actions: {
                fetchData: async function ({ commit }) {
                    const response = await getSomeRandomData()
                    commit("SET_WAREHOUSE", response)
                }
            },
            mutations: {
                SET_WAREHOUSE: (state, payload) => {
                    state.warehouse = [...payload]
                }
            },
            getters: {
                selselectedPrice: (state) => {
                    return state.warehouse[state.selectedItem].price
                },
                goodThings: (state) => {
                    return state.warehouse
                },
                totalPrice: (state) => {
                    return state.warehouse.reduce((a, item) => a+item.price, 0)
                }
            }
        })

        Vue.use(Vuex)

        let app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            store,
            created() {
                this.$store.dispatch('fetchData')
            },
            computed: {
                goodThings() {
                    return this.$store.getters.goodThings
                },
                totalPrice() {
                    return this.$store.getters.totalPrice
                }
            }
        })


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all in getter "secret" this line `state.x.forEach(e => e + 1)` is mutating the state. You can't do that in a getter. Only mutations can modify the state.

Comment: `state.x.forEach` you're trying to iterate over an undefined value, set x to an empty array instead of undefined.

Comment: That's not the point that I try to mutate. I could have filtered the data ... anything, but I did not call the getter in app, so I should not see the error (dev tools is calling it) ... I understand that it can be easy to set it as an empty array, the problem is that the app is too big to simply set some initial state :(

Comment: I have updated the snipped to more realistic case. You fetch some data and have index of selected item in store. It cannot be 0 or anything but undefined, since you don't have anything selected yet ... Later in app you want to check price of selected item, all good ... But dev tools is accessing the getter when it is not expected and returns errors in console and is stuck in loading state ... 
`index.html:61 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined`

Comment: @user8672473 Excuse me - but is this not exactly what the dev-tools are supposed to do? Evaluate your code and reveal potential errors? Yes, the error occurs because the getter is called within the dev tools and you encounter a TypeError. What this should tell you is that you should make sure your getters have a fallback in case `warehouse` is empty.

Comment: @MarcRo That sounds correct. App that I'm working on has now exactly 441 getters, and people developing it so far apparently did not use dev tools.  ... But I guess, there is no simple way out in this case, just to live without the tools or spend days if not weeks refactoring it.